# cambiar input check al recargar la pagina

Tags: javascript, checkbox, input-type

Tengo un checkbox que me gustaria que al recargar la página se pusiera en checked false, independientemente de como esté el checkbox antes de reiniciar la página.

¿Como podria hacerlo con JavaScript? Mi idea era la siguiente:

```
    function recarga(){
        document.getElementById("input").checked == false
    }

    if (window.onload){
        recarga()
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prueba con esto:

```js
function recarga() {
  document.getElementById("input").checked = true
}
window.onload = function() {
  recarga()
};
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="input">
```

En este caso te lo he dejado en **true** para que veas que queda marcado al cargar la página, pero lo dejas en `false` en tu código y ya está.

Básicamente he puesto bien la sintaxis para el evento [window.onload](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onload) y para la propiedad [checked](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_checkbox_checked.asp) que tu intentabas usar.

Comment: Perfecto gracias.